# how to change the plugin's param in launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, compressed, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I find that `image_transport` provides only one param (`image_transport`)for us to choose different compressed plugins. And if I set `image_transport` to `compressed`, I could change the param `jpeg_quality` with the help of `rqt_reconfigure`, but now, I want to change this param in launch file instead of `rqt_reconfigure`, how could I do?

Thanks first!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239497/how-to-change-the-plugin%27s-param-in-launch/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reconfigure parameters can be used like all other parameters in a launch file.

EDIT:

Let's say you have a node called `foo` in the package `foo_pkg` and want to change the `jpeg_quality` of the compressed image to 50 then the launch file should look like this:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="foo_pkg" type="foo" name="foo" >
    <param name="image/compressed/jpeg_quality" type="int" value="50"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2016-07-15**:
Thanks for your answer. If the parameters were defined in the inheritance class, I could reconfigure them in lanch.But the problem is that they are defined in the base class. How could I reconfigure  them in the launch file?
The instance of this problem is the jpeg quality in the image_transport.

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-07-16**:
Edited my answer with the solution to the problem. You can just specify the relative params like in the answer. That will lead to the param `/foo/image/compressed/jepg_quality` to be set.